# how can I get the data from IE developer tools?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-9

I want to get the data from post or network with developer tools.
Could I use some function from IE9?

Comment: what do you mean you want to get the data? Do you just want to view what data is being Posted?

Comment: If you have choice of browser, firebug for firefox is much better than the IE dev tools.

Comment: You may try Firebug Lite as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use IE9 dev tools to do this.

```
1) Bring up the dev tools by pressing `F12`
2) Click on the `Network` tab
3) Select `Start Capture`
```

Now `XMLHttpRequest` from your browser will be displayed, in the detail view you can display detailed information about the request.